# Kotlin Intent error

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following code and am getting an error with the Intent. It is because of the `this` I am fairly certain.

```
listView.onItemClickListener = object : OnItemClickListener {
            override
            fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View,
                            position: Int, id: Long) {
                val intent = Intent(this, MyActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

        }
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I got it working. I replaced "this" with "applicationContext"

Comment: @james If you've solved your problem, accept one of the answers or post your own if you have something else to add

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has two solutions you can use either:

```
val intent = Intent(this@YourActivity, MyActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
```

or :

```
 val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MyActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change it to getappicationcontext or declare global context and assign this to context.